# Accepting $_GET variables as a file path

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, get

I'm looking for a way to accept $_GET Variables as a file path, for example - `/page/test` would translate to `page.php?page=test`. I've searched and I can't find anything to help me, hence why i'm asking here.

I'm using Nginx on Ubuntu 13.04.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean URL rewriting `domain.tld/page/test` is routed to `domain.tld/page.php?page=test` if so you should look at URL rewrite for nginx rather than $_GET.   http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the [HttpRewriteModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule) installed, you should be able to configure it something like this;

```
rewrite  ^/page/(.*)$  /page.php?page=$1  last;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what if I wanted to rewrite a URL such as `http://domain.tld/test` which would then redirect to `http://domain.tld/index.php?page=test`?

Answer (score 0):

I usually prefer `try_files` over rewrites, here's how i would do it.

```
location ~ /page/(.*) {
    try_files page.php?page=$1 =404;
}
```

as for user1661022's question in the comments

```
location / {
     try_files index.php?page=$request_uri =404;
}
```